# Faint Beeping in earbuds?

Tags: audio, feed

I recently noticed that if I turn up all volumes on all of my devices (I have a pair of external speakers hooked up and my earbuds plugged in to the speakers) I hear this faint beeping. It sound like sticky keys. Others have said the 'hardware disconnect' sound but its not. I'm concerned about after re-search show that It could be feed back from a transmitting device. I got kind of paranoid and not sure what it is. How can I figure out what it is. It may be nothing. I have done research as I said and found similar things but not as I hear. The sticky keys sound has to dings to it. It sounds like the 1st half of it. I'm sorry if I cant describe it very well. Thanks!!

EDIT: It is not on any specific 'loop' it is random. I have also tried plugging it in to the computer, it is only louder.

EDIT 2:It gets louder and quiter apond change of volume on the computer does nothing. Changing the volume on the speakers make it louder

EDIT 3: I found out it matches the HDD activity light with a delay.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in your earbuds directly to the computer?

Comment: Just did, same thing but louder.

Comment: Are there any USB ports next to the place you're plugging in your earbuds? I have a laptop that makes my earbuds beep slightly when something is connected to the USB port next to them.

Comment: No, nearest thing is 3 feet or so away.

Comment: Without more information, people can only guess at what's causing it .  Can you record the sound and post a link to it?  Short of that, can you describe it better? (pitch, duration, pattern, etc.)

Comment: The sound is not loud enough to record enless i rig something to the microphone port

Comment: It is a middle to high pitch 'ding' lasts .5 of a second.

Comment: I removed the tag, I dont know what it was.

Comment: Your question expresses concern over the sound.  It may be distracting (especially because you are aware of it), but it can't harm anything and isn't a symptom of something harmful.

Comment: Now that I heard it it made me ponder what it was. I'm sorry if I came off as concerning. I just wondered what it was.

Comment: Watch your hard drive activity light and see if it matches the sound pattern? I had a similar 'noise' years ago that seemed to be drive interference, but I never investigated thoroughly.

Comment: I GOT IT!! IT MATCHES THE HDD ACTIVITY!!! THANKS!!!! (With a delay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a chance your phone is sitting on the desk anywhere near the speaker or headphone cable? GSM/LTE phones can cause interference with the cables.

Does it get louder or quieter with the speaker volume or system volume? This can help determine if it's just background noise on the audio system or if it's something being generated by the computer. If the system volume affects it then it's being generated somewhere. If it stays consistent, or only the physical speaker volume affects it then it isn't system noise.

There's a chance it's just background noise on the sound circuit, most integrated chips aren't totally isolated and can be affected by fluctuations in power on the rest of the system.

If it isn't so loud that it disrupts the sound of anything you're watching or listening to, I would ignore it as that.

Comment: It gets louder and quiter apond change of volume on the computer does nothing. Changing the volume on the speakers make it louder.

Comment: That makes sense, your speakers are acting as their own amplifier so they can boost it. But if the system volume has no effect than it's not a noise being generated by windows or the system, it's probably appearing in hardware by some sort of interference, either in the motherboard or along the wire (like the cell phone interference I mentioned). If it's not too loud to distract from what you're listing to I'd ignore it as something in the computer hardware itself can't really be fixed without an external sound card.

Comment: When I turn the tone up on the speakers it gets louder yet.

Comment: I moved my phone to another room and it is the same.

Comment: @DisplayWord:  See if you get the same thing with different earbuds.

Comment: Same thing with different buds.

Comment: Again, how loud is this noise? Is it louder than your music or movies, or does it's existence when the volume is maxed out just bother you?

Comment: about 1/4 the sound of a song.